# Kinect + OpenCV + OpenNI Fun Time

Tags: opencv, kinect, openni

So, I've been trying to set up my system so that I can get the video stream from the kinect in a development environment. My setup so far is this:

- Windows 7 32-bit,
- OpenCV 2.3.1 Super Pack (I'm assuming the big .exe is already set up to work with OpenNI)
- OpenNI (Latest Unstable)
- NITE
- PrimaSense
- My Kinect has refused to work with any drivers except the for the drivers from: "SensorKinect-Win-OpenSource32-5.0.3.3" Which I got from here: http://nicolas.burrus.name/index.php/Research/KinectRgbDemoV6

So far the following works:

- Nicholas's RGBDemo works with no problems, my kinect is detected and functions
- OpenNI's UserTracker.net.exe throws two errors: some procedure entry point cannot be located in the DLL XnDDK.dll. But after that, it works with little issue

My goal is to get the kinect_maps.cpp file from OpenCV working. It currently cannot detect the kinect.

So my question is, what can I try to bridge this gap between OpenCV and OpenNI/Nite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the pre-built libraries were not compiled against OPENNI SDK.
To enable kinect in OpenCV, you must download the source code, and compile by using Visual Studio 2010 (or MingW) and CMAKE. 
So, it requires extra work. You can obtain the source code [here](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv), by using git.
The explanation is rather lengthy, I do not wish to repeat what others have done here, so, [this](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#installation-by-making-your-own-libraries-from-the-source-files) page describes it concisely.

Happy developing.

Regards,
ikel